# Protractor script cannot be launched while testing with appium in IpadAir

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor, appium, appium-ios

I have an Angular website that i want to test using appium and protractor. I make the follwing config file :    ​

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 600000,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub',

  specs: [
    'testsuite/test1.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'safari',
   'appium-version': '1.4.13',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '9.3',
    deviceName: 'iPad Air'
},

  chromeOnly: false,

  frameworks:[
    'mocha',
    'chai'
  ],

mochaOpts: {

    defaultTimeoutInterval:1000000
}
};
```

test1.js  contain my test scripts generated by appium recorder by choosig Node.js option :

```
"use strict";

var wd = require("wd");
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

var expect = chai.expect;

chai.should();
chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = wd.transferPromiseness;

describe('my app', function() {
it('should make the login test',function()  {
var browser = wd.promiseChainRemote("0.0.0.0", 4723);

browser.init(desired).then(function() {
        return browser
                .elementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAButton[2]").sendKeys("0.22.82:4180/jws/fetablet_dev_T1000")

                .elementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAWebView[1]/UIAStaticText[1]").sendKeys("RET02")
                .elementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAButton[2]").sendKeys("RET02")
                .elementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAWebView[1]/UIAStaticText[2]").sendKeys("RET02")
                .fin(function() {
                        return browser.quit();
                });
}).done();
});
});
ᐧ
```

After running Appium server and launch the protractor.config.js file i got this error

```
​$ protractor protractor.conf.js
​​Using the selenium server at http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Error: ReferenceError: ᐧ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/qaquod/Development/qa/qa_fetablet/testsuite/test1.js:32:1)​​
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    ​​at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:71:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Jasmine.loadSpecs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:70:18)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 100
```

Comment: What is inside `test1.js`?

Comment: @alecxe i added it in description

Comment: test1.js contain scripts genrated by appium recorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmine fails to load the test because of the extra `ᐧ` character at the end of the spec, remove it.

Comment: you are right, but now the problem is : Failed : desired not defined

Comment: problem in that line : browser.init(desired).then(function()

Comment: @Emna well, I have not used the test spec generation feature, but I suspect this is where you can override the capabilities, see "Using wd" section [here](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot alecxe, i'm still trying in that line browser.init(desired).then(function() i changed with browser.wait(function()  but it tells me that this is not a function

Comment: i wonder if you can see this example that i want to run but i'm not able, thanks.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619518/cannot-run-protractor-scripts-using-code-generated-by-appium-for-ios-it-says-tha