# Cannot run protractor scripts using code generated by Appium for IOS it says that findelement is not a function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ios-simulator, protractor, appium

I want to automate my tests for an Angular JS site using Ipad Air simulator, appium and protractor but the problem that i'm not able to run correctly the script.

This is my config file

```
​exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 600000,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub',

  specs: [
    'testsuite/test3.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'safari',
   'appium-version': '1.4.13',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '9.3',
    deviceName: 'iPad Air'
},

  chromeOnly: false,

  baseUrl: 'http://10.0.22.82:4180/jws/fetablet_dev_T1000',

  frameworks:[
    'mocha',
    'chai'
  ],

mochaOpts: { 

    defaultTimeoutInterval:1000000
}         
};
```

My test3.js file contain :

```
"use strict";
var wd = require("wd");
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

var expect = chai.expect;

chai.should();
chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = wd.transferPromiseness;

describe('my app', function() {

it('should make the login test',function()  {

var desired = {
browserName: 'safari',
platformName:'iOS',
name:"This is an example for login test"
}

browser.get("0.22.82:4180/jws/fetablet_dev_T1000");


 browser.driver.findelement(by.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAWebView[1]/UIATextField[1]")).sendKeys("RET02");


});

});
```

While running `protractor.config.js` i have the following error and my test is failed, how can i identify elements?

```
​Using the selenium server at http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
F

Failures:​​
1) my app should make the login test
  Message:
    Failed: browser.driver.findelement is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: browser.driver.findelement is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/qaquod/Development/qa/qa_fetablet/testsuite/test3.js:26:17)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:96:23
        at new Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1043:7)
        at controlFlowExecute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:82:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2697:25
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: Run it("should make the login test") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:81:14)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/qaquod/Development/qa/qa_fetablet/testsuite/test3.js:15:1)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/qaquod/Development/qa/qa_fetablet/testsuite/test3.js:13:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.03 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
​
[launcher] safari #01 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code​ 1​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might probably want to change this for sure :

```
browser.driver.findelement(by.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAWebView[1]/UIATextField[1]")).sendKeys("RET02");
```

to

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAWebView[1]/UIATextField[1]")).sendKeys("RET02");

                   ^ //E instead of e
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser it changes the error for me, still not working but it tells me could not locate the element. The problem is that the web site is opened than it is closed immediately and the ipad simulator crashes!

Comment: @Emna : you can post that as a separate thread, seems some other issue. :)

Comment: Yes it's another one, i will accept this one and i opened a new issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630553/element-could-not-be-located-in-protractor-scripts-using-appium