# Element could not be located in protractor scripts using appium

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ios-simulator, protractor, appium

I want to automate my tests for an Angular JS site using Ipad Air simulator, appium and protractor but the problem that the test couldn't be passed successfully, it tells me that element couldn't be located and i'm sure about the xpath it's the same generated by appium.

This is my config file

```
​exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 600000,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub',

  specs: [
    'testsuite/test3.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'safari',
   'appium-version': '1.4.13',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '9.3',
    deviceName: 'iPad Air'
},

  chromeOnly: false,

  baseUrl: 'http://urlofmyapp',

  frameworks:[
    'jasmine'
  ],

mochaOpts: { 

    defaultTimeoutInterval:1000000
}         
};
```

My test3.js file contain :

```
"use strict";
var wd = require("wd");
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

var expect = chai.expect;

chai.should();
chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = wd.transferPromiseness;

describe('my app', function() {

it('should make the login test',function()  {

var desired = {
browserName: 'safari',
platformName:'iOS',
name:"This is an example for login test"
}
browser.ignoresynchronization=true;
browser.get("theurlofmyapp");


 browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAWebView[1]/UIATextField[1]")).sendKeys("RET02");


});

});
```

Here the error while running

> protractor protractor.config.js

[image: Protractor Error]

Comment: Try changing browser.driver.findelement to browser.findElement

Comment: Sorry i changed it already but i copied the old code here. I update it anyway the problem isnt from it.

Comment: I still see browser.driver.findElement in the question. Please try removing .driver and see if it works.

Comment: I m sorry i 'm connecting from the phone application, you are right

Answer (score 1):

Change `browser.driver.findElement` to `browser.findElement`

Comment: Now the problem becomes : No element found using locator : by.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAWebView[1]/UIATextField[1]"))

Comment: I will close this issue and i opened a new one with the new problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644922/while-running-protractor-script-with-appium-no-element-found-using-locator

Comment: The problem now is that when i delete driver as you told me, and put browser.findElementi got in appium log :  appium responding to client with driver.execute() result : null
and my test fails always !!!