# How can I run Appium Inspector on Windows?

Tags: automated-tests, appium

I'm new to Appium Mobile Automation tool. I followed few tutorials online and I am able to record tests using "Record" feature of Appium on Mac machine. However, my requirement is to generate Test cases on Windows machine. I was searching in Appium and stumbled upon this
[link](https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector)

I'm trying to run this on my local windows machine but there are following errors

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
file:///C:/browser/icons/style.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///C:/browser/styles/style.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///C:/node_modules/angular-ui-layout/src/ui-layout.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///C:/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
http://localhost:35729/livereload.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Can anyone guide how can I get this running on my Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use uiautomator viewer to find the path to identify elements because the recorder in windows isn't working.

Comment: Is appium inspector different than Recorder?

Comment: The inspector is the search icon, when you click  into it the opened window offer the record option, if you click into record your script will be generated

Comment: Ok, but here I'm taking about this https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector library in appium

Comment: So give me more details about what you want to know ?

Comment: I want to get XPath using this library. When i looked in to the code of this library, I found out it is based on Node and Angularjs. I'm new to Node or Angularjs so stuck in setting this up in my machine,

Comment: So you are using appium with protractor like me ?
I used it with java and testng so no problem with xpath, me too i have a problem while using with protractor with node generated code :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644922/while-running-protractor-script-with-appium-no-element-found-using-locator
But i have solved my problem by using css and model to locate elements xpath is not always recommended !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110357/discussion-between-dhaval-gulhane-and-emna).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install Appium Inspector separately. It comes with Appium Desktop. Just install Appium Desktop, then after starting the server, click the magnifying glass icon. That will open a launch window for Appium Inspector. Next, you need to define two key/value pairs. The first is platformName, you set it to either iOS or Android depending on your app type. The second is deviceName, set it to whatever you like. Then submit the form and it will start Appium Inspector.

Comment: since v1.22.0, Appium Inspector is built and distributed separately from Appium Desktop: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.22.0

Answer (score 0):

Appium Inspector has moved. Open Appium, click on the magnifying glass and it takes you to here:

https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector