# How can i identify element by model or by name in this the following example?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, web-inspector

I 'm using protractor to automate my tests, in order to click into the login button the action couldn't be executed when i tried to identify element by name, xpath, id ...

```
element(by.name('Login')).click();
```

It works only when i identify it by css :

```
element(by.css('.login-button')).click();
```

or

```
  element(by.css('button[ng-disabled=clicked]')).click();
```

But the problem the test is passed and user isn't redirected to home page even if i put browser.sleep(8000);
Is the login button identified by the right way with `element(by.css('button[ng-disabled=clicked]')).click();` ?

You can find here the html code :

```
 <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised login-button" ng-disabled="clicked" translate="login.LOGIN">Login</md-button> </section>

 </div> </fieldset> </form> <md-divider></md-divider> <footer class="login-footer"> <div layout="row" layout-align="center center"> <md-button ng-click="goToCustomerCare()" class="login-footer-link" translate="login.CUSTOMER_CARE">Contact Customer Care</md-button> <div> | </div> <md-button ng-click="showDisclaimer()" class="login-footer-link" translate="login.DISCLAIMER">Disclaimer</md-button> </div> </footer> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few buttons in the HTML code that you posted, but if you are trying to click the login button, you should be able to do

```
$('.md-raised').click(); or $('.md-raised.login-button').click();
```

This should search for the element by class.

Comment: you mean i stay with css but by another way : element(by.css('.md-raised.login-button]')).click();  ?

Comment: Yeah, I would give that a try.  You should be able to locate the button by the class name.  $ is a shorthand way of writing element(by.className()).  Here is an article that discusses some of them: http://luxiyalu.com/protractor-locators-selectors/

Comment: Still not working !! The problem is that the expect equal is passed after the click but no action is done for click !!!

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to click the button and the expect that you are using after?

Comment: You could try doing this: $('.md-raised').click().then(function(){console.log("here"); expect().toBe(); )};    This would make sure the expect isn't ran until after the click is performed.

Comment: Also can you try doing $('.md-raised').getText().then(function(text){ console.log(text); });   If it is locating the login button correctly, it should print out the text of "Login".

Comment: The problem is become more visible when i put console.log('msg before send keys and after ... ') i get all my msg in the console before even the web site is loaded in simulator !!!!

Comment: Is your application angular? if not, you need to add wait statements in so the page is loaded first then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110399/discussion-between-emna-and-rfodge).